# Deleting a subdirectory present in a directory inside a project Gitlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a requirement that I need to clean up GitLab repo, and need to remove all empty subdirectories present in a specific directory inside a specific project of a specific group.

Since, there are more than 10000 such directories that I need to remove, I was planning to do it programmatically using Gitlab python API.

However, I can't seem to find any way to list subdirectories or to remove them in GitLab Python API documentation. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `git` doesn't actually store directories themselves as objects that it manages.  It stores paths in `tree` objects, but once that part of the tree is empty they don't remove the sub-paths.

The simplest way to do the cleanup you want is simply remove all the files from the sub-directories and then reclone the repository.  It will not recreate the sub-folders that are empty.

[Newer versions of `git` may actually clean up sub-directories by the way, but older ones won't.  My `git` 2.31 will, eg]

Comment: Accepting your answer, as I found out the same thing. Will work with my IT team to update our git version. Thanks.